# How to get TableLayout cell values in Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have `TableView` of 3x3 rows and col.

```
    var tableLayout = FindViewById<TableLayout>(Resource.Id.tableLayout);
    rowCount = 3; columnCount = 3;
    TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
        {
            var cell = new TextView(this);
            cell.SetText("(" + GetRandomItem() + ")", TextView.BufferType.Normal);
            row.AddView(cell);
        }
        tableLayout.AddView(row);
    }
```

And assigning random values. using below function

```
private string GetRandomItem()
        {
            var charList = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
            var random = new Random();
            int index = random.Next(0,charList.Count);
            return charList[index];
        }
```

Now how can I get those values based on `index` on `TableLayout`

Comment: do you mean to get one cell's value after the tablelayout add the random values ?

Comment: I want to iterate throughout the table on btn click event. If I need any specific cell value, I can get it

Comment: Please check the following solution. Is it what you need?

Comment: could it work ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT - Need to check it.

Comment: yes,let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Does it work now ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT - I did not get time to test it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> iterate throughout the table

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
   {
     Android.Widget.TableRow row = (Android.Widget.TableRow)tableLayout.GetChildAt(i);
     for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
        {
          TextView cell = (TextView) row.GetChildAt(j);
          var value = cell.Text;
        }
   }
```

> get any specific cell value

e.g. get the cell(1,2) value

```
Android.Widget.TableRow row = (Android.Widget.TableRow)tableLayout.GetChildAt(1);
TextView cell = (TextView) row.GetChildAt(2);
var value = cell.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this solution,

```
var tableLayout = FindViewById<TableLayout>(Resource.Id.tableLayout);
          int  rowCount = 3;int  columnCount = 3;
            TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
            {
                TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
                for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
                {
                    var cell = new TextView(this);
                    cell.SetText("(" + GetRandomItem(j) + ")", TextView.BufferType.Normal);
                    row.AddView(cell);
                }
                tableLayout.AddView(row);
            }

private string GetRandomItem(int index)
        {
            var charList = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
            //var random = new Random();
            //int index = random.Next(0, charList.Count);
            return charList[index];
        }
```

output is :

(A)(B)(C)

(A)(B)(C)

(A)(B)(C)